# ClassNotFoundException but class is on classpath and in same jar

Tags: java, classloader, classnotfoundexception

**Question**

what is causing the `ClassNotFoundException`?

**Details**

I'm getting a `ClassNotFoundException` when trying to load a class that I believe to be on the classpath - the class is `com.ldbc.driver.db.BasicDb`, an implementation of `com.ldbc.driver.db.Db`

When I try to run this command:

```
java -cp core/target/core-0.1.jar:distribution/target/ldbc-driver-0.1.tar.gz com.ldbc.driver.Client -db com.ldbc.driver.db.BasicDb
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ldbc.driver.db.BasicDb
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at com.ldbc.driver.util.ClassLoaderHelper.loadClass(ClassLoaderHelper.java:163)
    at com.ldbc.driver.util.ClassLoaderHelper.loadDb(ClassLoaderHelper.java:29)
    at com.ldbc.driver.Client.start(Client.java:167)
    at com.ldbc.driver.Client.main(Client.java:80)
```

It occurs on this line:

```
Class<?> loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass( className );
```

To check if the class is on the classpath (in one of my jars) I did the following:

```
grep "BasicDb" distribution/target/ldbc-driver-0.1.tar.gz
```

-> returned **0** matches

```
grep "BasicDb" core/target/core-0.1.jar
```

-> returned **1** match: `Binary file core/target/core-0.1.jar matches`

If I import the class at compile time it works fine, i.e. the following works:

```
import com.ldbc.driver.db.basic.BasicDb;
```

Though my `grep` tests seem to indicate the class **is** on the classpath and is there **only once**, I wanted to test if for some reason different classes were attached to a different root classloader.

But when printing them out it seems that the same classloader is used everywhere:

```
ClassLoaderHelper classloader = sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@489a44f1
Client classloader = sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@489a44f1
```

Comment: A `.tar.gz` on the classpath? I'd be surprised if that'd work at all!

Comment: turns out this is not the source of my problem, but thanks for pointing it out - I added this for no good reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`com.ldbc.driver.db.BasicDb` versus what you have in your import `com.ldbc.driver.db.basic.BasicDb`

You launched your app with the wrong package name for `BasicDb`, as an application argument.

```
java -cp core/target/core-0.1.jar:distribution/target/ldbc-driver-0.1.tar.gz com.ldbc.driver.Client -db com.ldbc.driver.db.BasicDb
```